# Ethics on Bounty Award when best answer only solved half of the problem?

Tags: discussion, bounty, ethics

A little while ago, I wrote a question on regular old stackoverflow.com, and received nothing but thin air as this roadblocking problem haunted me.  So naturally, when able to, I started a Bounty.

The Bounty wasn't high mind you, I don't exactly have a lot of Reputation to just throw around, but I set it to +50, and after a few hours I started getting some responses and potential answers. I remained heavily involved obviously, answering questions and responding to potential workarounds and fixes.  For what it's worth to me; if I was putting up a chunk of my profile up for grabs, I want the right answer and not some work around.

Well, someone popped up, and gave a nice and informative answer that I totally appreciated. The only problem was, his answer didn't fix my problem.  But it was exactly one half of the issue at hand. Using the fix to allow myself to dive deeper, I tried a fix I discovered on my own, and it worked.  Problem solved.

Here's where it get's a little more problematic: No one could have known the answer based on the information I provided. Or rather, on the information I failed to provide.  The source code in question that was the ultimate fix, was never provided, as at the time I wrote the question it not only seemed irrelevant, but entirely dissociated. I mentioned the code (that was the eventual problem) by name only, but not by source code snippet.

So, what should I do? Technically the most correct answer didn't solve the issue, but it **was** the most helpful answer in the set. I've set the answer as Correct regardless to give the guy the appropriate boost, but what about the Bounty?

Comment: You wont get the bounty back if you dont award it.  On the other hand, since it sounds like you might never have gotten to the answer without that help, awarding it to that person seems warranted.  The bounty did its job - got your question more attention, so why not?  The fact that it was not the "full" answer seems not to be a shortcoming of the answer, but of the question.

Comment: That's a brilliant and sobering perspective. You are correct, the bounty did indeed do it's job, and thus should be awarded so.  So if the bounty does not come back, is it just lost in the ether then? If so, what's the point of the bounty time-limit?

Comment: well, how would you feel if you gave up your 50 rep and no one was in a hurry to answer because it will still be there tomorrow?

Comment: Haha fair enough!

Comment: @Plutonix That's great! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wont get the bounty back if you dont award it.  The bounty is actually for the extra notice your question gets, not necessarily The Answer.

On the other hand, since *it sounds like you might never have gotten to the answer without that help*, awarding it to that person seems warranted. The bounty did its job - got your question more attention, so why not?   There are other rules where an answer posted after the bounty is posted which gets upvoted, that answer will get half the bounty if you do not accept one.

The fact that it was not the "full" answer seems not to be a shortcoming of the answer, but of the question.

For a lackadaisical answer which *could have* been fully answered, I might just upvote help and perhaps post an answer.  That seems not to be the case here.

Comment: +1 for saying "The fact that it was not the "full" answer seems not to be a shortcoming of the answer, but of the question"  That is why they should get the bounty.  The solved the question that was asked, even if it isn't what the OP meant to ask.

Answer (score 9):

Award the bounty and an upvote to the guys answer that helped the most. Then add an answer of your own wrapping the whole thing up in a complete package that can be the canonical answer. Mark that as correct.

Comment: Plutonix's comments (and eventual answer) are what lead to an answer to my moral dilemma, but your answer is exactly what I ended up doing overall.